# LAG : not fluid movement on JAVA Box2D game

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, interpolation, fluid

I'm a newbie game developer. I've been trying to develop a game using LibGDX and Box2D physics engine, but when I export my android application, it is not working as it should be.

This problem is happening in some devices; it does not matter if it's an old device or a new one.

For example the app is working well in Sony Xperia Z1, Motorola XT615, LG L1, LG L3, LG L5,etc. However, in Sony Xperia U, Motorola Moto E,Samsung Galaxy's is not working like I expect.

You can see a non-fluid behavior when the object is moving across the screen. That's the problem I have. It's like a stutter effect, not fluid.

I read on forums that It could be a FPS (frames per second) problem when I set the time step in the world. So, I am using a fixed time step method and with the remainder time that I get in "accumulator" I interpolate it. I read these articles:

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/
http://saltares.com/blog/games/fixing-your-timestep-in-libgdx-and-box2d/

to learn the fixed time step and interpolation method, but I think that there is a fail in my code that I can't see.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

SpriteBatch batch;                                                                                      
Texture img;                                                                                             
Sprite sprite;                                                                                             
Body body;                                                                                 
Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;                                                                           
OrthographicCamera camera;                                                                                              
World world;                                                                                                                  
final float PixelsToMeters=100f;                                                                                                  
float step = 1.0f / 60.0f ,alpha;                                                                                              
Vector2 currentPosition,lastPosition,position;                                                                                           
double currentTime,accumulator,lastAngle,currentAngle;                                                                                            
final float BODY_WIDTH=95f,BODY_HEIGHT=95f;


@Override
public void create () {
    world= new World(new Vector2(0f,-9.8f),true);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("circulo.png");
    sprite=new Sprite(img);

    //BODY DEFINITION
    BodyDef bodydef=new BodyDef();
    bodydef.type= BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodydef.position.set(-3.5f,-2.4f);
    body=world.createBody(bodydef);

    CircleShape shape=new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius((sprite.getWidth()/2)/PixelsToMeters);

    FixtureDef fixturedef=new FixtureDef();
    fixturedef.shape=shape;
    fixturedef.density=0.1f;
    fixturedef.restitution=1f;
    fixturedef.friction=0.5f;
    body.createFixture(fixturedef);
    shape.dispose();

    //SET SPRITE POSITION
    sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x *PixelsToMeters - BODY_WIDTH/2, 
            body.getPosition().y * PixelsToMeters - BODY_HEIGHT/2);

    //THROW CIRCLE 
    body.setLinearVelocity(3.5f,9.5f);

    lastPosition=new Vector2();
    position=new Vector2();
    camera=new 

OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        camera.update();

        double newTime = TimeUtils.millis() / 1000.0;
        double frameTime = Math.min(newTime - currentTime, 0.25);
        float deltaTime = (float)frameTime;

        currentTime = newTime;
        accumulator+=deltaTime;

        while (accumulator >= step) {

            //SAVE LAST BODY POSITION AND ANGLE
            lastPosition.x=body.getPosition().x;
            lastPosition.y=body.getPosition().y;
            lastAngle=body.getAngle();

            world.step(step, 8, 3);
            accumulator -= step;
        }

        //SAVE CURRENT BODY POSITION AND ANGLE
        currentPosition= new Vector2(body.getPosition().x,body.getPosition().y);
        currentAngle=body.getAngle();

        alpha=(float) (accumulator/step);

        position.x = lastPosition.x + (currentPosition.x - lastPosition.x) * alpha;
        position.y = lastPosition.y + (currentPosition.y - lastPosition.y) * alpha;

        sprite.setPosition(position.x * PixelsToMeters - BODY_WIDTH/2, position.y * PixelsToMeters
                -BODY_HEIGHT/2);
        sprite.setRotation((float)Math.toDegrees(lastAngle+(currentAngle-lastAngle)*alpha));

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
        batch.draw(sprite, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(),
                sprite.getOriginX(), sprite.getOriginY(),
                sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight(), sprite.getScaleX(),
                sprite.getScaleY(), sprite.getRotation());
    batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        world.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the sprites position to that of the body instead of calculating the position each frame? Could be a float problem since you get different behavior on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem before using box2d, small stuttering when physics steps took longer than 1/60 seconds.

I also tried interpolation and read lots of articles about it without any success.

In the end I am not using fixed timestep at all (just delta to the world step) and all goes smoothly with box2d.

But if you still want to use fixed step, i have some suggestions:

- Use `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` as it gives you a smoothed delta with n previous frames.
- Use deltaTime in the world step loop:`world.step(deltaTime, 8, 3);` and `accumulator -= deltaTime`.

Hope it helps!